# Почему не срабатывает блок catch в методе Main

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть такой код

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication37
{
    class Test
    {
        public Test()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread t1 = new System.Threading.Thread(Foo);
            System.Threading.Thread t2 = new System.Threading.Thread(Foo);
            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();
        }
        public void Foo()
        {
            try
            {
                throw new OverflowException();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Специально созданное исключение");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                Test p = new Test();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Какая-то ошибка");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В нем в 2-х потоках запускается один и тот же метод, генерирующий исключение. Как видно, то после обработки исключения в методе `Foo`, это же исключение передается на обработку выше по иерархии. Но почему-то `catch` в методе `Main` не срабатывает вообще. Почему ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исключения, запущенные через класс Thread, ловятся в блоке catch только в текущем потоке, в котором они были сгенерированы. 
Соответственно, вы в `main` не можете поймать повторно-сгенерированное исключение.

Чтобы поймать исключение в другом потоке, можно воспользоваться [асинхронным механизмом запуска делегатов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.110).aspx)(вместо использование класса Thread). Измените конструктор класс `Test` на следующий код

```
    public Test()
    {
        var action = new Action(foo);
        IAsyncResult result = action.BeginInvoke(null, null);
        try
        {
            action.EndInvoke(result);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
           throw;
        }
    }
```

Теперь в методе `main` вы можете ловить ваши исключения, сгенерированные в другом потоке.

Comment: Спасибо. А есть ли какой-то способ все-таки его поймать ? Может хитрость какая-то ?

Comment: @PolyakovSergey, есть напишу сейчас.

Comment: @PolyakovSergey, обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться

Comment: Ну и зачем делать BeginInvoke - если EndInvoke делается сразу же?

Comment: Концептуально проще наверное всё же через async/await. Плюс это всё же рекомендованный паттерн для асинхронности.

Answer (score 2):

Хотел бы поделиться еще одним способом отлова необработанных исключений, без завершения приложения. Этот способ является некорректным, и использовать его нужно только в самых крайних случаях, когда никакие адекватные способы не помогают:

1) В файле конфигурации возвращаем режим `CLR` к поведению версии `1.0-1.1`:

```
<runtime>
    <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1"/>
</runtime>
```

2) Для отлова необработанных исключений подписываемся на событие `UnhandledException`:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine((e.ExceptionObject as Exception).Message + " CLR IsTerminating: " + e.IsTerminating);
}
```

3) В конструкторе класса `Test` ожидаем завершения потоков:

```
t1.Join();
t2.Join();
```

---

Весь код выглядит примерно так:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
            var p = new Test();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((e.ExceptionObject as Exception).Message + " CLR IsTerminating: " + e.IsTerminating);
        }
    }

    class Test
    {
        public Test()
        {
            var t1 = new Thread(Foo);
            var t2 = new Thread(Foo);
            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();
            t1.Join();
            t2.Join();
        }

        public void Foo()
        {
            try
            {
                throw new OverflowException();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Специально созданное исключение");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

p.s. при запуске под отладчиком `Visual Studio` данный способ не сработает, и студия покажет исключение. При запуске самого `exe` - исключения не будет.

Answer (score 1):

1. Запускаем рабочий процесс с генерацией исключения
2. Отлавливаем внутри рабочей процедуры исключение во внешний `exception`
3. `thread.join` - ожидаем выполнения рабочего процесса
4. Обрабатываем в `main` отловленные исключения

Можно также в случае Net 4.0 воспользоваться классом `ConcurrentQueue`, для сбора всех исключений внутри других ниток, а далее после выполнения потоков можно вытащить исключения.